# Using Debut's slate to create a popup cart

Tags: popup, shopify, cart, slatejs

I'm trying to use slate's `_hideCartPopup` and `_showCartPopup` to respond to onclick on the cart's anchor tag. I'm using the latest `debut` theme.

tried with this but I'm having error..

```
 var siteheadercar = document.querySelector('.site-header__cart');
 siteheadercar.addEventListener('click', function() {
     theme.Product._showCartPopup();
 });
```

`Uncaught TypeError: theme.Product._showCartPopup is not a function`

Comment: are you sure, there is code related to popup into theme already?

Comment: @Onkar yes I am.. https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/themes/os/themes-by-shopify/debut/settings#add-to-cart-notification .. However, I want to extend the functionality by making it a popup cart.. figured I could use the show/hide popup function to do that